# Bit-shifting in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Why is it that:

```
return 1 | (1 << 32) // returns 0x00000001
```

but:

```
return 6 | (1 << 32) // returns 0x00000007
```

I was expecting the latter to return 0x00000006. What type of bitmask can be OR-ed with the expression to generate 0x00000006 for 6 | (1 << 32)?

Comment: You can always perform the bitwise-or of 6 with 0 to get 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java only uses the last 5 bits of the bit-shift argument when shifting `int`s.  So `1 << 32` is equivalent to `1 << 0`, or just `1`.

The `1` bit is already set in `1`, so `1 | 1` is `1`.  Only the last 8 bits shown for clarity:

```
   0000 0001 (1)
or 0000 0001 (1)
------------
   0000 0001 (1)
```

But the `1` bit is not set in `6`, so `6 | 1` sets the bit and the number becomes `7`.  It's working as expected.

```
   0000 0110 (6)
or 0000 0001 (1)
------------
   0000 0111 (7)
```

**Addition**

In response to the addition to the question:

`6` has only 2 bits set (`0000 0110`), so any number that you could bitwise-OR with `6` and still have `6` must have all bits clear that are clear in `6`.  That leaves just 4 choices, combinations of the set bits of `6` being set or cleared:

- 0 (0000 0000)
- 2 (0000 0010)
- 4 (0000 0100)
- 6 (0000 0110)

Any other `int` will set at least one other bit, making the output something other than `6`.

Comment: If Java only uses the last 5 bits of the bit-shift argument, does it produce any sort of warning if the value of the argument exceeds 5 bits?

Comment: @EricJ. No, but if you shift by a large constant 32 or bigger, your IDE might warn you.